# Will routing via via httpVerb attribute and "Route" attribute result in different routes?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, attributes, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have simple customer controller (asp net core 3.0) that looks like the following :

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v1.0/{controller}")]
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
}
```

What is the difference setting up route token `{id}` via the `[HttpGet]` or `[Route(...)]` 
 for example :

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(string id)
    {
       . . .
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(string id)
    {
      . . .
    }
```

will they resolve to similar route:  `api/v1.0/{controller}/{id}`?

Comment: There's no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be the same , from [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0) :

> Attribute routing can also make use of the Http[Verb] attributes such as HttpPostAttribute. All of these attributes can accept a route template.

If using `[Route(...)]` on an action method , the action will accept all HTTP methods. So it's recommended to use more specific `Http*Verb*Attributes` in rest api :

> When building a REST API, it's rare that you will want to use [Route(...)] on an action method as the action will accept all HTTP methods. It's better to use the more specific Http*Verb*Attributes to be precise about what your API supports. Clients of REST APIs are expected to know what paths and HTTP verbs map to specific logical operations.